# Display .ppt /.pptx file using vb.net for vs2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mime-types

I am using following code for displaying .pdf file but the same code is not working for .ppt / .pptx files. Need suggestions.

```
If file.Name.Contains(Left(lblMth.Text, 3) & lblYr.Text) Then
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.ClearHeaders()

    Dim path As String = file.FullName 'strLine & GridView1.Rows(index).Cells(1).Text()
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Dim buffer As [Byte]() = client.DownloadData(path)

    If buffer IsNot Nothing Then
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the correct content type for the file type you are sending:

**.ppt**

`application/vnd.ms-powerpoint`

**.pptx**

`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`

See [Office MIME Types](http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php) for more reference